# jVectormap Dynamic bootstrap modal cloning dynamic content div on click

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, jvectormap

I have a map that i am trying to use a dynamic bootstrap modal when a region is clicked and i would prefer to use the label displayed on hover as the div the content is being cloned from in the modal.

So the use would click on Texas and a modal would be created and clone the div with the id=modal-Texas. The content div is dynamic and i am unable to change the ID of Texas.

Also in my code i have the modal showing but it seems to be not removng the modal on close and putting a modal in a modal.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

$('#contacts-map').css({ 
        width: '100%',
        height: '450px',
        padding: '15px'
    });

```
var customModal = $('<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm col-sm-12 col-xs-12 modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="modal-us-tx"><div class="modal-dialog modal-sm"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></div><div class="modal-body"></div></div></div></div>');

var RColor = '#007cc4'
var stateRedirects = [
    "US-VA", //Virginia
    "US-PA", //Pennsylvania
    "US-TN", //Tennessee
    "US-WV", //West Virginia
    "US-NV", //Nevada
    "US-TX", //Texas
    "US-NH", //New Hampshire
    "US-NY", //New York
    "US-HI", //Hawaii
    "US-VT", //Vermont
    "US-NM", //New Mexico
    "US-NC", //North Carolina
    "US-ND", //North Dakota
    "US-NE", //Nebraska
    "US-LA", //Louisiana
    "US-SD", //South Dakota
    "US-DC", //District of Columbia
    "US-DE", //Delaware
    "US-FL", //Florida
    "US-CT", //Connecticut
    "US-WA", //Washington
    "US-KS", //Kansas
    "US-WI", //Wisconsin
    "US-OR", //Oregon
    "US-KY", //Kentucky
    "US-ME", //Maine
    "US-OH", //Ohio
    "US-OK", //Oklahoma
    "US-ID", //Idaho
    "US-WY", //Wyoming
    "US-UT", //Utah
    "US-IN", //Indiana
    "US-IL", //Illinois
    "US-AK", //Alaska
    "US-NJ", //New Jersey
    "US-CO", //Colorado
    "US-MD", //Maryland
    "US-MA", //Massachusetts
    "US-AL", //Alabama
    "US-MO", //Missouri
    "US-MN", //Minnesota
    "US-CA", //California
    "US-IA", //Iowa
    "US-MI", //Michigan
    "US-GA", //Georgia
    "US-AZ", //Arizona
    "US-MT", //Montana
    "US-MS", //Mississippi
    "US-SC", //South Carolina
    "US-RI", //Rhode Island
    "US-AR" //Arkansas
];
var newHTML = $.map(stateRedirects, function(value) {
    return(value);
});

$('#contacts-map').vectorMap({



    map: 'us_en',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    zoomOnScroll: false,
    zoomButtons: false,
    regionStyle: {
        initial: {
            fill: '#0071A4',
            scaleColors: ['#b7bdc3', '#a2aaad'],
            "fill-opacity": 1,
            stroke: '#ffffff',
            "stroke-width": 1,
            "stroke-opacity": 1
        },
        hover: {
            "fill-opacity": 0.8
        },
        selected: {
            fill: '#0071A4'
        },
        selectedHover: {
            fill: '#a2aaad'
        }
    },
    series: {
        regions: [{
            values: {
            //"el" : RColor,                
            //"be" : RColor
            },
        attribute: 'fill'
        }]
    },      
    onLabelShow: function(event, label, code){
        if($.inArray(code, stateRedirects) > -1){
            //do nothing
        }
        else if (code) { //if a state is not specified in var stateRedirects then prevent default
            event.preventDefault();
        }                   
    },      
    onRegionOver: function(event, code){
        if($.inArray(code, stateRedirects) > -1){
            $('#jvectormap1_' + code).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }
        else if (code) { //if a state is not specified in var stateRedirects then prevent default
            event.preventDefault();
        }                   
    },
    onRegionClick: function (event, code) {            

        if($.inArray(code, stateRedirects) > -1){
            $('body').append(customModal);
            $('#modal-'+code.toLowerCase()).clone().appendTo('.modal .modal-body');             
            $('.modal').modal({
              backdrop: false
            });

            $('.modal').on('hidden', function(){                    
                $('.modal .modal-body').html('');
                $('body').remove(customModal);
            });
        }
        else if (code) { //if a state is not specified in var stateRedirects then prevent default
            //event.preventDefault();
        }   

    }
    });
```

});

I also have a fiddle but am at my wits end of how to get this to work. In the example you will see i have a div with content for Texas and California to test with but when you click on them they do not work and all other regions show the modal as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/ymgkkuzL/39/

Comment: Getting closer but need to figure out how to use the label on hover for the div to look for to clone and append to the modal body div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/ymgkkuzL/46/

Comment: SOOO CLOSE! I have it almost working but would prefer to use the label that you see on hover rather than making an another array to match up the code with the div ID name. See my example here http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/ymgkkuzL/62/

Comment: Here is the latest revision. This is about the best i can get it and would love any or all suggestions to make it better and easier to implement. http://jsfiddle.net/abennington/ymgkkuzL/78/